# Why aren't the options in my dynamically inserted webform showing up?

Tags: 7, blocks, webforms

I've created a webform with one question that includes a list of checkboxes.

I made the webform available as a block, and am rendering the block in my template using:

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'client-block-#####');
print render($block['content']);
?>
```

However, when the form renders, I see the title of the question and the submit button, but the options are not visible. How can I debug why the checkbox options aren't showing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked admin/reports/dblog and it turns out the select_or_other plugin wasn't properly installed, stopping the options from showing up at all.